# Python, returning the integer from a tuple from an input

Tags: python

I am trying to make the input command streamlined, I don't know if I can explain this but here it goes.

```
    out = input()
    planOne = int(out)
    planet = listplanets[planOne]
    print(planet)
```

So `listplanets` is a tuple, if I input a number such as 0, it will return `Mercury`, how do I make it so I can input `mercury` and it will return `Mercury`. I want to keep the tuple format and I will also need the integer value of the tuple item in say `var1`. Would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me out. PS I know, I am a massive noob XD.
Edit: This is how my tuple is made

```
listplanets = ("Mercury"), (0.378), ("Venus"), (0.907), ("Mars"), (0.377), ("Io"), (0.1835), ("Europa"), (0.1335), ("Ganymede"), (0.1448), ("Callisto"), (0.1264)
```

Edit:
I am now using a dictionary, as suggested by you kind people.

```
    listplanets = {
        "Mercury": "Mercury",
        "Mercury2": 0.378,
        "Venus": "Venus",
        "Venus2": 0.907,
        "Mars": "Mars",
        "Mars2": 0.377,
        "Io": "Io",
        "Io2": 0.1835,
        "Europa": "Europa",
        "Europa2": 0.1335,
        "Ganymede": "Ganymede",
        "Ganymede2": 0.1448,
        "Callisto": "Callisto",
        "Callisto2": 0.1264}
```

My reason for structuring it this way was for printing purposes, I am overcomplicating this!
I am not sure if it is against the rules to ask another question but it does relate to this post.
I am now trying to have it so when you type in `mercury` it will output `On the planet of Mercury`, this code below is not working for me, more help would be massively appreciated!

```
    out = input().capitalize()
    if out == listplanets:
        print("On the planet of", listplanets[out])
    else:
        print("That was an incorrect format! Try again.")
        planets()
```

For anyone that is curious, here is my code (Reason why it is not text is because this is my assignment, the anti plagerise tool would say I am copying my own code! XD):
[image: First part of the code]

[image: Second part]

[image: Last part]

[image: This didn't show clearly]

### ---------------------------------------

The previous part was not shown clearly and that is why there is an image there
[image]

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: what's the point of iputting `"mercury"` for getting `"Mercury"`. I don't understand. If that all your program does, just use `out.title()`

Comment: Using a dictionary is the best way.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I am trying to streamline the code, I do not really know what I am talking about but I have my reasons for doing it this way.

Comment: Don't ask 2 questions in 1. That would make the answers section a mess. Anyway your problem is that you check if the input from the user is the whole dict. That would never be true. Try, `if out in listplanets`. But why do you have each planet twice with a number? The user will have to know that...

Comment: @LV98 Thank you for the advice, I have implemented your suggestion!

Comment: You don't need to repeat the same thing over and over in your dict.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry I thought it might have done so, thanks for that advice and I've done it this way because I am overcomplicating it because I am a massive noob, XD!

Comment: Ok... So why are you overcomplicating? What's the point of having a dict entry as `"Mercury": "Mercury"`? Just do `"Mercury": 0.378`

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Thank you for replying, I don't know really what I am doing so I will do whatever it takes to get this code working, even if it is a bit messy! :)

Comment: @friendywill, I think you need to study more about [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Well I am not too experienced in python, so I'm just messing about really. I appreciate the advice though.

Comment: @Tomerikoo The whole code is working now! I will have to show you a picture of the code so it can explain itself why it is the way it is. (I want to show a picture because it is an assignment, if I had it in text the anti plagiariser tool would think my assignment was plagiarised on this site! XD)

Comment: Still I find it weird to have 2 keys for each planet, it means that in order to get the mass, the user actually needs to input `mercury2` which is not intuitive. I understand that you are a beginner and that's fine, we were all once... But you should embrace the right idiomatic way of doing stuff. I would recommend changing your dict structure to something more appropriate

Comment: @Tomerikoo Well with mine if the user inputs Mercury, it will give all the information needed, I will include another picture to show you.

Comment: Yeah I see that, I am just saying that the way to get there is not the best. I am just saying all that keeping in my mind you're a beginner, so for you to get better and improve. An important thing about writing code is to remeber that you write it only once, but read and modify it many times. It is important that code will be as clear as possible and easy for a reader unfamiliar with it to understand what;s going on.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks, I will definitely do it for my next bit of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the slice operator directly `listplanets[out]` on a dictionary.

And you don't have to repeat the same thing over and over`"mercury": "Mercury"`.
Use this format for your dictionary,

```
listplanets = {"Mercury": 0.378, "Venus": 0.907, "Mars": 0.377, "Io": 0.1835, "Europa": 0.1335, "Ganymede": 0.1448, "Call
```

and try this

```
out = input()
if out.isdigit():    #check if the input is digit
    print(list(listplanets.keys())[int(out)])    #gets all key values to a list and so slicing can done 
else:
    print(listplanets[out.capitalize()])    #capitalize first letter
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have figured it out but I will mark this as the answer because mine is very similar. :)

Comment: At least the second part

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep it tuple format you have to loop through your data like this:

```
# Data is given like this. First name and then value related to it.
listplanets = ("Mercury"), (0.378), ("Venus"), (0.907), ("Mars"), (0.377), ("Io"), (0.1835), ("Europa"), (0.1335), ("Ganymede"), (0.1448), ("Callisto"), (0.1264)


out = input("Planet: ")
for i in range(len(listplanets)):
    if isinstance(listplanets[i], float):
        # Skip values
        continue
    if out.lower() == listplanets[i].lower():
        print ("{}: {}".format(listplanets[i], listplanets[i+1]))
```

But using dictionary is much better, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Well, that did not work, I clarified my tuple structure if you wanna have another go :).

Comment: Well, that is quite problematic tuple structure. Even tuple of tuples like `(("Mercury",0.378),("Venus",0.907),...)` would be much better.  But I can update the code the way it works with your data.

Comment: I'll take your suggestion to change into a dictionary I think, I will see how I go and thank you for that advice.

Comment: Excellent idea :). And depending what you are doing, you can use nested dictionaries and save many attributes in same variable. Like `{"Mercury":{"position":1,"weight":0.378...},{"Venus":{"position":2,....}}`

Comment: I have now updated the code! Do you know of any way of dealing with the new problem now? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dictionaries doesn't have indexes. They have keys.

Answer (score -1):

How about this code?

```py
# listplanets = ('Mercury', 'Earth')


In [19]: new_listplanets = [(index, {planet.lower(): planet}) for index, planet in enumerate(listplanets)]
# [(0, {'mercury': 'Mercury'}), (1, {'earth': 'Earth'})]

In [20]: new_listplanets[0][0]
Out[20]: 0

In [21]: new_listplanets[0][1]['mercury']
Out[21]: 'Mercury'
```

Comment: That couldn't work if idea is using `input` function for user input.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it will not work in my case but I still appreciate this!